# Upload image using kendo UI upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to upload an image file using kendo ui upload and here is what I'm doing

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <label for="file">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="AVATAAR" id="AVATAAR" />
</form>

var upload = $("#AVATAAR").data("kendoUpload");
if (!upload) {
    $("#AVATAAR").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            saveUrl: "**What do I to put here?**",
            removeUrl: "remove",
            autoUpload: true
        }
    });
}
```

I have a controller, `CodeUserSettingsController.cs`, where I have written code to save the image to a folder.

Can anybody please tell me what to put in `saveUrl`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have written the code to save the image in some Action, so the url is simply `~/CodeUserSettings/<yourActionName>`...

Comment: i tried giving saveUrl:/CodeUserSettings/POST but its saying resource cannot be found

Comment: The name of your action is "POST"? nevertheless don't forget to put the URL into quotes `"/CodeUserSettings/POST"`...

Comment: same error :-( this is the apicontroller i'm using        public HttpResponseMessage POST()
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["AVATAAR"];
            string savepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images/tmp/");
            //string filename = postedFile.FileName;
            string filename = "Lighthouse.jpg";
            if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
            postedFile.SaveAs(savepath + filename);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

Comment: @Deepak oh ok, you're using api controller, so it depends on your route config... Basically it is "/api/{controller}/{id}", thus in your case : "/api/CodeUserSettings".

Comment: now its calling the method...but HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["AVATAAR"];  is showing null...what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you seen the sample controller code given on this [page](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/async.html)? the signature of your action should be : `public ActionResult YourActionName(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) { ... }` which gives you access to the list of the uploaded files (in your case, there will be only one file...

Answer (score 0):

In `saveUrl` you need to insert the path of the controller, in your case CodeUserSettingsController.cs.

For more clarity look the following examples:

- If the controller and image upload files are in the same directory you must write: `"saveUrl: CodeUserSettingsController.cs"`
- If the controller and image upload files are in different directory you must write: `saveUrl: "path/to/the/directory/CodeUserSettingsController.cs"`

Answer (score -1):

[SaveUrl can be Controller name and method name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L0QP.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.